# UISplitViewController inside a tabbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller, appdelegate

[image]

The picture above is a basic layout of the storyboard that I have. `UITabBarController` is the parent view controller and one of its child is a `UISplitViewController` embedded inside a `UINavigationController`.

What I am trying to do is send the indexpath selected in menuVC (leftviewcontroller) in the split view to the detailVC (rightviewcontroller). I will be using a `ContainerViewController` in the detail view and use the indexpath to load the correct view controller after that. Right now I am trying to pass the indexpath to the detail view.

*LeftViewController.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RightViewController.h"

@class RightViewController;

@interface LeftViewController : UITableViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate>
{
    NSArray *menuArray;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) RightViewController *detailViewController;

@end
```

*LeftViewController.m*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    menuArray = @[@"Option 1", @"Option 2", @"Option 3", @"Option 4"];

    self.detailViewController = (RightViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
    self.splitViewController.delegate = self;
}
```

This is what I have in .m file along with the usual tableview functions and segue to send the indexpath.

I do not have any codes in the `Appdelegate.m`, which I assume is the missing code.. but since splitviewcontroller is not the root here, I am not sure how I should proceed.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with segue. Nevermind.